# error converting shapefile to geoJSON with Ogre online tool

Tags: shapefile, geojson, attribute-table, ogr2ogr

I am using on online tool built with ogr2ogr to convert shapefiles to geoJSON:
http://ogre.adc4gis.com/

It's worked well except for one shapefile, and I can't see why...
The shapefile has only six attribute columns: ObjectID, a shape field, a date field and three text fields..when I try to convert all that I get is:

{"errors":["Unexpected token ,"]}

I tried selecting 'skip failures' in the convertor, and I have looked for some inconsistency in the attribute names and columns but I don't see anything unusual.

What could be giving me this odd result?

[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with comma character somewhere. Can you share the shapefile?

Comment: I checked for that, and I can't see a comma anywhere--I'm not sure how to share an actual shapefile here but I added a screenshot of the attribute table above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not give this tool a try?

URL: https://9revolution9.com/en/tools/geo/shp_geojson/

[image: https://9revolution9.com/en/tools/geo/shp_geojson/]

Comment: Since you are related to this product, you should add a disclaimer stating this. The stackexchange community tends to frown upon self-promotion.